# Deleting multiple rows with array of _id mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to delete multiple rows at once in Mongoose but I can only think/find of doing this with an `each` and removing individually.

```
var arrays = [ [ 560324b994a552efdeb128a2 ],
  [ 560324b994a552efdeb128a3 ],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [ 560324b994a552efdeb128a0 ],
  [ 560324b994a552efdeb128a1 ],
  [] ]

someModel.remove(arrays);
```

Also if possible I'd like it to remove only the items that have a value, although this is easy to overcome if I need to remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove multiple documents with the [$in query operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) as follows

```
var idsArray = ['560324b994a552efdeb128a0', '560324bd5f4f4df6s128a0'];

someModel.remove({ id: { $in: idsArray } }, function (err) {
    if (err) return callback("Error while deleting " + err.message);
    callback(null, "Some useful message here...");
});
```